# Dynamic Links (Android App Links) not to prompt "open with" Android 6.0+

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

How do I make the setup in order for a Dynamic Link (from Fireabase) to open the app directly and not ask first to chose between the browser or the app.

I've set up Firebase Dynamic Links and added the certificate fingerprint sha256 to the firebase project settings. Selecting either options(browser or app) will end up opening the app, but it still asks.

As I read this is possible with Android App Links on Android 6.0 and over.

The intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
             <data android:host="my-custom-subdomain.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
             <data android:host="my-custom-subdomain.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its hard to say without any code shown, but for that to work, you must set the `android:autoVerify` tag in your  `intent-filter` to `true`.

Besides you need to deploy and `assetlinks.json` in the following direction> `https://domain.name/.well-known/` where and you must do it for al domain that your intent filter supports.

The process is well explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations)

PD: here is an example of an `assetlinks.json`

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
  "namespace": "android_app",
  "package_name": "com.example",
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints":

  ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, what you mentioned is accurate. I wasn't so clear about the context, I'm trying to do this using Dynamic Links service from Firebase. 
The  `android:autoVerify="true"` was set in my manifest.
I did get the  assetlinks.json, but I can't set it on Firebase's  `page.link` domain,  I can only add the sha256 in the project's settings, which I did.

Comment: Oh Dynamic links.. gotcha. Have you visited the well-known path for you generated page.link domain? Im pretty sure FB uploads the assetlinks

Comment: I've checked the path and it's there alright.
Manage to find the issue, after generating the Digital Asset File in App Links Assistent I forgot to press 'Link and Verify' button, doing so and reinstalling the app solved it, now it opens as expected. Thanks!

Comment: The https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations link seems to now not work anymore. Is there a new place where this information exists?

Answer (score 0):

I the issue was that press Link and Verify button in App Links Assistent.

For others facing similar issues, thing to check:

- if the intent filter is added in manifest;
- if the corect sha256 is added to the Firebase project;
- if you pressed the 'Link and Verify button';
- if you uninstalled and reinstalled the app with the new manifest